# PHP array structure, simplify for understanding

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, structure

I have massive array with next elements:

```
array(
    array('url' => 'http://someurl.com', 'param' => array(false,true,true,true)), 
    array(...),
    array(...),
    ...
)
```

"boolean" values means some parameters(noindex, header, footer, sidebar).

I need modify this array for better understanding(some user can`t understand what means "boolean" values).

I can add param names like this:

```
array(
    array(
         'url' => 'http://someurl.com', 
         'param' => array(
                         'noindex' => false, 
                         'header' => true,
                         'footer' => true,
                         'sidebar' => true
                    )
    ), 
    array(...),
    array(...),
    ...
)
```

but this method increases array size too much.

How can I simplify array?

Thanks!

Comment: imCaps why is there a limit to you array size? Memory?

Comment: if you can live with those parameters no being named and access it with an index, and if you don't have more than 32 or 64 parameters you could store all parameters in a single integer value that you would define in binary; If I take your example, it would result in 0111 which translates to the Integer `7` => All it takes to store 64 values is 4 bytes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I have found is using class constants and bitwise operators.

```
// Here we declare constants
const NOINDEX =     0b00000001,
      HEADER =      0b00000010,
      FOOTER =      0b00000100,
      SIDEBAR =     0b00001000;

// Here is array that I can understand without comparing boolean values with documentation
$urls = array(
        array('url' => 'http://someurl.com/', 'param' => self::NOINDEX | self::HEADER | self::FOOTER),
        array('url' => 'http://somesecondurl.me/blogs', 'param' => self::HEADER | self::FOOTER | self::SIDEBAR), 
        ...

//And of course using it
 $param = $urls[i]['param'];

 if ($param & self::HEADER) // Means that url have param HEADER
 if ($param & self::FOOTER) ...
 if ($param & self::SIDEBAR) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify for understanding, without pay it price.

The only way is add comment for array.

```
array(
    array(
         'url' => 'http://someurl.com', 
         'param' => array(
                          false, //noindex
                          true,//header
                    )
    ), 
    array(...),
    array(...),
    ...
)
```

But if all element of the array is the same you can do this.

```
array(
'url' => array('url1','url2',...),
'param'=>array(
    'noindex'=>array(true,false,...),
    'header'=>array(true,false,...)
));
```

I think it's not too important to decrease memory usage. because if you don't assign index, PHP add index automatically. there is no too different between array with string or integer.

I think you can have second code without any problem.

Comment: With more than 100 urls, this row ('noindex'=>array(true,false,...)) should be very long

Comment: @imCaps this row should be very long anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify array as you mentioned, you can use associative arrays. However, this approach only fits if url has a unique values:

```
$tArray = array($tUrl1 =>array(
         'param' => array(
                         'noindex' => false, 
                         'header' => true,
                         'footer' => true,
                         'sidebar' => true
                    )
    ),
    $tUrl2 =>array(
         'param' => array(
                         'noindex' => false, 
                         'header' => true,
                         'footer' => true,
                         'sidebar' => true
                    )
    )
)
```

The advantage of using this approach is ease to call nested values like param.

```
$tArray[$tUrl1]['param'];
```